device is still connected but the network does not work
I have a problem when turning on the PC which is running Ubuntu 22.04. It connects to the network, however after a short time the device is still connected but the network does not work.


Are you sure the problem is with your computer and not the network? Have you tried with a different computer?

it's just in my computer the other devices work it , im reset my Ubuntu for default mode after that the network It broke down
